# Multidimensional array sorting based on number with a different format

Tags: php

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [hashtag] => a7e87329b5eab8578f4f1098a152d6f4
            [title] => Flower
            [order] => 3-1-9
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [hashtag] => b24ce0cd392a5b0b8dedc66c25213594
            [title] => Free
            [order] => 2-7-5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [hashtag] => e7d31fc0602fb2ede144d18cdffd816b
            [title] => Ready
            [order] => 2-6-3
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [hashtag] => e7d31fc0602fb2ede144d18cdffd816b
            [title] => Ready
            [order] => 3-6-3
        )
)
```

I need sort based on the 'order' in descending order

Comment: What is the sorting logic you want to apply? Add clarification to the question please.

Comment: sort based on the 'order' in descending order

Comment: do you try `krsort` ? it sort array (Descending Order), According to Key

Comment: @Amrutha Please uprove the answers and upvote it if you find useful , Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below code

```
$multi  = array(
            array(
                    'hashtag'=>'a7e87329b5eab8578f4f1098a152d6f4',
                    'title'=>'Flower',
                    'order'=>'3-1-9'
                ),
            array(
                    'hashtag'=>'b24ce0cd392a5b0b8dedc66c25213594',
                    'title'=>'Free',
                    'order'=>'2-7-5'
                ),
            array(
                    'hashtag'=>'e7d31fc0602fb2ede144d18cdffd816b',
                    'title'=>'Ready',
                    'order'=>'2-6-3'
                ),
            array(
                    'hashtag'=>'e7d31fc0602fb2ede144d18cdffd816b',
                    'title'=>'Ready',
                    'order'=>'3-6-3'
                ),
        );

function sortByOrder($a, $b) {  
    return str_replace("-","", $a['order']) -  str_replace("-","",$b['order']);
    //For decending use the below code
    //return str_replace("-","", $b['order']) -  str_replace("-","",$a['order']);
}
usort($multi, 'sortByOrder');           
echo '<pre>';
print_r($multi);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/psOMD)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) `function` on those values, passing `-` as the separator, so you will get an `array` of numeric strings from your dash-separated numbers. Convert your numeric strings into numbers before you do a comparison and then sort them, like:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    $aArray = explode("-", $a["order"]);
    $bArray = explode("-", $b["order"]);
    for ($index = 0; $index < min([count[$aArray], count[$bArray]]); $index++) {
        $intA = (int)$aArray[$index];
        $intB = (int)$bArray[$index];
        if ($intA !== $intB) return (($intA < $intB) ? 1 : -1); //Descending
    }
    if (count($aArray) === count($bArray)) return 0;
    return ((count($aArray) < count($bArray)) ? 1 : -1); //Descending
}
```

and then use this:

```
usort($yourArray, "cmp");
```

Answer (score 0):

With usort () and an array comparison after explode with the PHP 7 Spaceship Operator <=>:

```
usort($multi, function($a,$b){
  return explode("-",$b['order']) <=> explode("-",$a['order']);
});
```

If order always has the fixed format like 3-1-9 (and not 31-4-345) then explode can be omitted:

```
usort($multi, function($a,$b){return $b['order'] <=> $a['order'];});
```